# Error en slicing de lista en python

Tags: python-3.x

¡Hola buenas!

He querido hacer un programa al que le pases unos valores, que los almacene en una lista y que posteriormente haga una suma desde una parte a otra de la lista usando slicing.

```py
datos =  []

cant_dat = input("Cuántos? ->")

for a in range(int(cant_dat)):
    x = input("x" +str(a+1) + ": ")
    n = input("n" +str(a+1) + ": ")

    dato = [int(x), int(n)]
    datos.append(dato)

print("x\tn\tN")

for a in datos:
    print("{}".format(a[0]),end="\t")
    print("{}\t{}".format(a[1]), sum(datos[0:(datos.index(a))+1]), end="\n")
```

Si ejecutáis el programa, ponéis que `cant_dat` es 3 y todos los demás datos son 10, el resultado debería de ser:

```py
x    n    N
10   10   10
10   10   20
10   10   30
```

Creía que estaba todo correcto hasta que me apareció el error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Estadística.py", line 16, in <module>
    print("{}\t{}".format(a[1]), sum(datos[0:(datos.index(a))+1]), end="\n")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

Tengo claro que es en la segunda parte del `.format()` pero no tengo claro el por qué me aparece el error de tipo.

Gracias

Comment: ¿podrías mostrar un ejemplo [mcve]? Para saber qué debería salir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problema inicial (errata?)

Tal como tienes el `print()` hay un error de sintaxis, pues al `format()` le pasas sólo un parámetro, cuando la cadena tiene dos "lugares" `{}` a sustituir. Además le estás pasando a `print()` como segundo parámetro el resultado de un `sum()`, que imagino tendría que ser en realidad el segundo parámetro del `format()`.

Es decir, debería estar así:

```
print("{}\t{}".format(a[1], sum(datos[0:(datos.index(a))+1])), end="\n")
```

Por otro lado, si lo ponemos así, entonces aparece el error que describes en la pregunta (si no aparecía otro), por lo que supondré que así es como tú lo tienes en realidad, y que fue un error al copiarlo aqui.

## Problema al que te refieres

Pues bien, ¿Cuál es el error que presenta este código (una vez corregido este problema)?

Resulta que los elementos de la lista `datos` son a su vez listas, con dos elementos cada una. Al iterar por el bucle, la variable `a` irá tomando los valores de cada una de estas sublistas. Si por ejemplo el usuario respondió 10 para x0 y 10 para n0 , entonces en la primera iteración del bucle `a` vale `[10, 10]`.

Cuando buscas `datos.index(a)`, te devolverá el índice del *primer elemento* dentro de `datos` cuyo valor sea `a`. Si hay varios elementos con el mismo valor te devolverá el índice *del primero* (volveremos a esto después).

En este caso devolvería 0 puesto que el primer elemento vale `[10, 10]`, por lo que tu *slice* sería `datos[0:1]`, lo cual de momento encaja con lo que querías. Pero el problema es que en ese *slice* los elementos son listas. Es decir, a `sum()` le estás pasando una lista cuyos elementos son listas, en este caso sería `sum([[10, 10]])`.

Y aquí es donde aparece el error. Lo que hace `sum()` es inicializar con 0 una suma para después ir añadiéndole cada elemento de la lista que recibe como parámetro. El primer elemento sería la lista `[10, 10]`, por lo que `sum()` intentará hacer la suma `0 + [10, 10]` y de ahí el error de que no puede sumar un `int` con una `list`.

### Otro problema nuevo

Realmente no está muy claro qué es lo que quieres sumar en realidad. Podría tratarse del primer elemento de cada lista (las x) o del segundo (las n). El ejemplo que das tampoco ayuda a resolver la ambigüedad, ya que en él has dado el mismo valor a todas las x y todas las n, pero dado que el encabezado de la respuesta llama `N` a esa suma, voy a suponer que se trata de sumar las n.

En ese caso, si llamo `trozo` a una variable que contenga el *slice* que hayas extraído, el cual tiene como elementos listas, y quieres sumar el segundo elemento de todas esas sublistas, harías:

```
suma = sum(dato[1] for dato in trozo)
```

Llevando esto a tu código quedaría así (aún no funcionará, luego veremos por qué):

```
for a in datos:
    trozo = datos[0:datos.index(a)+1]
    suma = sum(dato[1] for dato in trozo)
    print("{}\t{}\t{}".format(a[0], a[1], suma))
```

Si lo ejecutas dando como datos de entrada 3 y después todo 10, obtendrás esta salida (que no es lo que esperabas):

```
x       n       N
10      10      10
10      10      10
10      10      10
```

El problema ahora es lo que antes comenté sobre `datos.index()` y es que no te vale para datos repetidos porque se queda con el primero que encuentre.

### Solución

La solución es no buscar el índice, sino usarlo también como parte del bucle para que se vaya incrementando en cada iteración. Para esto puedes usar `enumerate()` que te devuelve el índice de cada iteración además del valor extraído de la lista. Así:

```
for i, a in enumerate(datos):
    suma = sum(dato[1] for dato in datos[0:i+1])
    print("{}\t{}\t{}".format(a[0], a[1], suma))
```

Ahora sí saldrá el resultado que muestras en la pregunta.